# Convert fractions stored as characters to float64

Tags: python, pandas, fractions

Say we have this df:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
            'value': ['18 4/2', '2 2/2', '8.5'],
            'country': ['USA', 'Canada', 'Switzerland']
    })

Out:

        value   country
    0   18 4/2  USA
    1   2 2/2   Canada
    2   8.5     Switzerland
```

Note the 'value' column stores an *object* type:

```
df.dtypes

Out:

value      object
country    object
dtype: object
```

My question: how do we convert 'value' to decimal, while also changing the data type to float64? Note that one value (8.5) is already a decimal, and should be kept so. Desired output:

```
desired_output = pd.DataFrame({
        'value': [20, 3, 8.5],
        'country': ['USA', 'Canada', 'Switzerland']
})


    value   country
0   20.0    USA
1   3.0     Canada
2   8.5     Switzerland


desired_output.dtypes

value       float64
country     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Probably the best way to do it is to split the strings at spaces and backslashes and parse it from there

Comment: The question has "overhead". In essence the pandas data frame layer, and the list are not really relevant. The question is really how to convert a string like `'18 4/2'` to the number 20. Why not focus it purely on that?

Comment: thanks @trincot, I'll try to keep it more focused next time. Here I thought I should define a df and a list since I have observations in my df (I work on a df actually) that are already in decimals. So I don't just need to convert strings to decimals, but also to keep existing decimals how they are. And this I didn't know how to do. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `replace` the space with the sign + and then `apply` `eval`

```
print(df['value'].str.replace(' ', '+').apply(eval))
0    20.0
1     3.0
2     8.5
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

or using [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html)

```
df['value'] = pd.eval(df['value'].str.replace(' ', '+')).astype(float)
print(df)
  value      country
0  20.0          USA
1   3.0       Canada
2   8.5  Switzerland
```

Comment: merci beaucoup! Worked like a charm

Comment: @johnjohn haha I was wondering why you commented in French, then I saw I wrote a couple of words in French, must be tired already ...

Comment: haha good coincidence since my native language is French! All best

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with @Ben.T's answer but since I already played around, here's my attempt.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...             'value': ['18 4/2', '2 2/2', '8.5'],
...             'country': ['USA', 'Canada', 'Switzerland']
...     })
>>> df
    value      country
0  18 4/2          USA
1   2 2/2       Canada
2     8.5  Switzerland
>>> def foo(s):
...     try:
...             return float(s)
...     except ValueError:
...             pass
...     w, f = s.split()
...     n, d = f.split('/')
...     w, n, d = map(int, (w, n, d))
...     return w + n / d
...
>>> foo('1')
1.0
>>> foo('18 4/2')
20.0
>>> df['value'] = df['value'].apply(foo)
>>> df
   value      country
0   20.0          USA
1    3.0       Canada
2    8.5  Switzerland
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------   --------------  -----
 0   value    3 non-null      float64
 1   country  3 non-null      object
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
>>>
```

Comment: many thanks! and you were right to share your own attempt, since I will also learn from it!